# Extremely high MSE/MAE for Ridge Regression(sklearn) when the label is directly calculated from the features

Tags: scikit-learn, mse, ridge-regression

Edit: Removing `TransformedTargetRegressor` and adding more info as requested.

Edit2: There were 18K rows where the relation did not hold. I'm sorry :(.  After removing those rows and upon @Ben Reiniger's advice, I used LinearRegression and the metrics looked more saner. The new metrics are pasted below.

Original Question:

Given `totalRevenue` and `costOfRevenue`, I'm trying to predict `grossProfit`. Given that it's a simple formula `totalRevenue  - costOfRevenue = grossProfit`, I was expecting that the following code would work. Is it a matter of hyperparameter optimization or have I missed some data cleaning. I have tried all the scalers and other regressions in `sklearn` but I don't see any big difference.

```
# X(107002 rows × 2 columns)
+--------------+---------------+
| totalRevenue | costOfRevenue |
+--------------+---------------+
| 2.256510e+05 | 2.333100e+04  |
| 1.183960e+05 | 2.857000e+04  |
| 2.500000e+05 | 1.693000e+05  |
| 1.750000e+05 | 8.307500e+04  |
| 3.905000e+09 | 1.240000e+09  |
+--------------+---------------+

# y
+--------------+
| 2.023200e+05 |
| 8.982600e+04 |
| 8.070000e+04 |
| 9.192500e+04 |
| 2.665000e+09 |
+--------------+
Name: grossProfit, Length: 107002, dtype: float64

# Training


import numpy as np
import sklearn

from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=13)

x_scaler = StandardScaler()

pipe_l = Pipeline([
        ('scaler', x_scaler),
        ('regressor', Ridge())
        ])


regr = pipe_l

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)

print('R2 score: {0:.2f}'.format(sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)))
print('Mean Absolute Error:', sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))


print("Scaler Mean:",x_scaler.mean_)
print("Scaler Var:", x_scaler.var_)
print("Estimator Coefficient:",regr.steps[1][1].coef_)
```

## Output of above metrics after training(Old Metrics with 18k rows which did not confirm to the relation)

```
R2 score: 0.69
Mean Absolute Error: 37216342513.01034
Mean Squared Error: 7.601569571667974e+23
Root Mean Squared Error: 871869805169.7842
Scaler Mean: [1.26326695e+13 2.14785735e+14]
Scaler Var: [1.24609190e+31 2.04306993e+32]
Estimator Coefficient: [1.16354874e+15 2.59046205e+09]
```

## Ridge(After removing the 18k bad rows)

```
R2 score: 1.00
Mean Absolute Error: 15659273.260432156
Mean Squared Error: 8.539990125466045e+16
Root Mean Squared Error: 292232614.97420245
Scaler Mean: [1.57566809e+11 9.62274405e+10]
Scaler Var: [1.20924187e+25 5.95764210e+24]
Estimator Coefficient: [ 3.47663586e+12 -2.44005648e+12]
```

## LinearRegression(After removing the 18K rows)

```
R2 score: 1.00
Mean Absolute Error: 0.00017393178061611583
Mean Squared Error: 4.68109129068828e-06
Root Mean Squared Error: 0.0021635829752261132
Scaler Mean: [1.57566809e+11 9.62274405e+10]
Scaler Var: [1.20924187e+25 5.95764210e+24]
Estimator Coefficient: [ 3.47741552e+12 -2.44082816e+12]
```

Comment: Could you provide the ridge regression's coefficients, and the scalers' mean/var?

Comment: updated. I simplified the code. Thanks!

Comment: The scores you report are based on the unscaled labels and predictions, so the MSE and MAE make sense and are not _relatively_ large. But the R2 score is worryingly low; it may be only due to the regularization penalty: try LinearRegression?

Comment: It had 18k bad rows :(. Please see edit2. And LinearRegression worked well. I have posted the metrics above. Thanks so much!

Comment: @BenReiniger. would you care to put your above comment as the answer so that I can mark it as the answer, it helped me significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To summarize the comment thread into an answer)

Your original scores:

```
Mean Absolute Error: 37216342513.01034
Root Mean Squared Error: 871869805169.7842
```

are based on the original-scale target variable and are between $10^{10}$ and $10^{12}$, at least significantly smaller than the mean of the features (and the target)?  So these aren't automatically bad scores, although for a perfect relationship we should hope for better.  Furthermore, a 0.69 R2 values is pretty low, no scale-consciousness needed.

That both of the model's coefficients came out positive is the most worrisome point.  I'm glad you identified the culprit rows; I don't know how I would have diagnosed that from here.

Your new ridge regression still has "large" errors, but significantly smaller than before, and quite small compared to the feature/target scale.  And now the coefficients have different signs.  (I think if you'd left the `TransformedTargetRegressor` in, you'd get largely the same results, but with less penalization.)

Finally, when such an exact relationship is the truth, it makes sense *not* to penalize the regression.  Your coefficients here are a little bit larger, and the errors drop away to nearly nothing, especially considering the scale of the target.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a the standard scaler twice, once in your pipeline and once more in the `TransformedTargetRegressor`. Next to that, you are only fitting the scaler, never actually scaling the inputs (i.e. transforming the input).

Comment: Thanks! re: using the scaler twice. the first one is for X and the second one in `TransformedTargetRegressor` is for y. Even if I take it out, I get very similar results. Also, my understanding of pipelines is that `fit` will call `fit_transform` for all but the last. ref: https://iaml.it/blog/optimizing-sklearn-pipelines/images/pipeline-diagram.png and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html

Comment: I tried doing it manually but the same magnitude of error.
```python
scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train_transform = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_transform = scaler.transform(X_test)

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train_transform, y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(X_test_transform)
```

Comment: Looking at the image you linked it indeed would make sense that the `fit` method will `fit_transform` in all steps except the last one. However, when I quickly checked using your data it seemed that `X_train` was not properly scaled before the `regr.fit` was called. Can you check this on your side?

Comment: thank you for checking :).  Do you mean that `train_test_split` should have scaled `X_train` for me? if I understand correctly `X_train` would be scaled after it is passed to `regr.fit` as the scaling would happen inside?

Comment: No, I meant that `X_train` should be getting scaled after being passes to `regr.fit`, however checking this on my end this did not seem the case.

Comment: oh, that's a good observation. I'll check on my side.

Comment: How do you check X_train should be getting scaled after being passed in? Are you checking the value of X_train after `regr.fit` or are you able to plug in some diagnostic just before X_train is passed to the LinearRegressor/Ridge?